# How do you get categories as a nested array in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x

I want to make a custom element that produces a list of categories and their subcategories.

My problem is the categories and subcategories come through as one single level array.

How can I produce a nested array so I can use fluid to loop over it?

```
10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
10 {
        if.isTrue.field = categories
        table = sys_category
        selectFields = sys_category.*
        pidInList = 55
        recursive = 999
        as = categories
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need a custom DataProcessor. But that's not too hard to do - have a look at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/CustomDataProcessing.html#content-elements-custom-data-processor . Just give a note if you need further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can nest data processors too, you just have to make sure to select parents only for the first level. Then you can get their children on the second level based on the parent's uid:

```
10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
10 {
        if.isTrue.field = categories
        table = sys_category
        selectFields = sys_category.*
        pidInList = 55
        recursive = 999
        where = parent = 0
        as = categories
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            10 {
                    table = sys_category
                    selectFields = sys_category.*
                    pidInList = 55
                    recursive = 999
                    where.dataWrap = parent = {field:uid}
                    as = subcategories
            }
        }
}
```

Still it would be nice to get a specific category processor for the core.
See https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82010

Comment: Thank you. I have just tried this but it's giving me an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax` Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Try again, there was a . instead of : between field and uid

Comment: Of course, sometimes you can me blinded from simple solutions. One last question: how can I format the first level `where` to use the categories field in the element? eg `where.dataWrap = parent = {field:categories}`

Comment: parent is a field of the sys_category table for internal relations between categories, so this won't match the categories field of the actual parent record of another table.

You will have to go for sys_category_record_mm to get the actual relation.

Comment: What I mean is, my content element has the categories field so the user can select the parent. So I want that first `where` to use the category that was chosen.

Comment: Still those have to be fetched from the MM table, since the field itself will just contain the number of relations.